# MVC file browse not working with songs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, upload

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadMusic", "Music", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="file" name="files" id="mus-inp" multiple="multiple" />
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" type="submit">Upload</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

I am trying to create an uploader for music however, when I click on upload button after selecting .mp3 file it just stops working, no exception or anything and it doesn't reach the 'UploadMusic' action controller either.

The problem seems to be enctype = "multipart/form-data" because if I remove this it reaches the controller. Also all of my code works when uploading images just not music.

If I am doing this wrong please say. I am using the HttpPostedFileBase method to upload.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the files were above 4mb. Use `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="x" />` in the global web.config where 'x' is the max size of the file in KB otherwise your program will crash and not tell you.